# python fabric - passing host as arguemnt

Tags: python, fabric

Below is my fab file.

```
env.hosts = ['111.111.111.111']
env.user = "root"
env.key_filename = "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"
def chef():
    run('mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/')]
```

How do I pass host as an argument so I can call like this?

```
fab test host=111.111.111.111

env.hosts = [host]
env.user = "root"
env.key_filename = "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"
def chef():
    run('mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
./fabfile.py
from fabric.api import run, env

env.user = "root"
env.key_filename = "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"
def test():
    run("mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/")

---
fabric:~$ fab test -H 111.111.111.111
>>>[192.168.99.20] Executing task 'test'
>>>[192.168.99.20] run: mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/
>>>
>>>Done.
```

[-H] opstion sets env.hosts to the given comma-delimited list of host strings.
Please check [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/usage/fab.html) for detailed fab command usag

or like this.

```
./fabfile.py
def setenv(host=None):
    if host is not None:
        env.hosts= [host]
    env.user = "ubuntu"
    env.key_filename = "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa"

def test():
    run("mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/")

---
fabric:~$ fab setenv:web01 test
(snip)
```

Comment: Great answer!  Please make it clearer by adding more description beyond just the examples.